# How to use ffmpeg to send video stream to another server that gives exactly same quality as manually copying the file to that server?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I tried doing this

```
ffmpeg -i tcp://192.168.1.41:5000?listen -c copy out.avi
```

and have another client publish to this server using

```
ffmpeg -i 1.avi -map 0 -c copy -f mjpeg tcp://192.168.1.41:5000
```

However, the ffprobe results I get for these two files are

```
Invalid return value 0 for stream protocol
    Last message repeated 1 times
Input #0, avi, from 'out2.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:08.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 31181 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 2048x1536, 31321 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 50 tbn, 50 tbc
```

and

```
[mjpeg @ 0x177aea0] Changeing bps to 8
Input #0, avi, from '1.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.20.4 
  Duration: 00:00:40.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6235 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 2048x1536, 6264 kb/s, 5 fps, 5 tbr, 5 tbn, 5 tbc
```

Although the file size is the same, I am not sure if they are still the same. Based on the output, it seems not. Can I know why?

What should be the command to send exact same stream to a remote server?

***Update with the suggestion from @Mulvya***

The output of using `-f nut` is as follows, which I don't quite understand why:

```
Invalid return value 0 for stream protocol
    Last message repeated 1 times
[nut @ 0x55cdee5959c0] No main startcode found.
tcp://192.168.1.41:5000?listen: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: Are these interlaced images?

Comment: I am not sure what interlaced images mean. The original video is produced using opencv by adding new frame one by one.

Comment: `mjpeg` is a raw stream, so ffmpeg has to assign a framerate if one isn't manually supplied. Default fps is 25 but yours shows as 50. Which may happen if at the receiving end, ffmpeg thinks there are two frames in a packet. Usually, those would be pair of interlaced pictures.

Comment: @Mulvya is there a way to make the fps the same? e.g. a command that cos everything to be copied exactly.

Comment: Don't stream a raw stream i.e. use `-f nut tcp://192.168.1.41:5000` in 2nd command.

Comment: only -c copy will at least give same size of files but different ffprobe output @Mulvya

Comment: Why do you want to obtain exactly the original file by streaming?

Comment: @aleb Actually I just need exactly same quality. However, I am not sure how I should gauge the same quality other than file size? Previously, I thought -crf 0 means best quality but how it is bigger than the original file by many factors which doesnt make sense. Why is it much bigger and yet the quality is not better? (Not better because you can't have a converted file that is higher quality than the original file)

Comment: @aleb Are you implying streaming has to lose some quality?

Comment: Just to make sure it's not the container, try with `-f avi`

Comment: Check whether it's the same quality by doing something like `ffmpeg -i IN -c:v copy OUT.mkv` for *both* the source and the copy, and compare that.